# Did the provisions end between Judges 7 and 8?

Tags: judges

In Judges 7:8 (NASB)

> So the three hundred men took the people’s provisions and their trumpets in their hands. And Gideon dismissed all the other men of Israel, each to his tent, but retained the three hundred men; and the camp of Midian was below him in the valley.

In Judges 8:4-5 (NASB)

> 4 Then Gideon and the three hundred men who were with him came to the Jordan and crossed over, exhausted yet still pursuing. 5 And he said to the men of Succoth, “Please give loaves of bread to the people who are following me, for they are exhausted, and I am pursuing Zebah and Zalmunna, the kings of Midian.”

Did the provisions end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "provisions" in Judges 7:8 are those of the men who were rejected from Gideon's army - 9700 men who knelt down to drink.  Since these men did not need their equipment and supplies, they were taken over by the remaining 300 men.

Later, in Judges 8, when the 300 men had been in battle for more than a day (or two?), they needed food and water and asked the surrounding towns to help.  That is, the food the 300 men had taken over from the 9700 men had been exhausted and they needed more as they were "exhausted" from the battle.  Judges 8:4.

We are not told what the "provisions" (Judges 7:8) were but I would be amazed if it did not include some food, especially bread.

Comment: Ok! Could it also be that the provisions didn't include bread (or that sort of food)?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - we are not told what the provisions were but I would be amazed if it did not include some food.

Comment: Can you include that in the answer too? Thank you!

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - done!